# How do i fetch only internal messages from O365 using Graph API

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365-apps

I wan't to fetch only messages that are only internal to organization. 
Right now the way i see is fetch domains first then for each message see if from/sender domain belongs to that message , based on that differentiate.

But this is **lengthy** process and **not a foolproof** technique.
Is there any GRAPH API query i can use which readily provides this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not apear that the REST API queries for Office 365 includes this information directly in the messages. From the [Version 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations) And the [Beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/beta/mail-rest-operations-beta#GetMessages) this is not included in message output.

However, it looks like you might be able to get it from the REST API via the headers.

Try the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?$select=internetMessageHeaders&$top=1
```

This takes top one messages and shows you the email header of the message.
In the header look for `X-OriginatorOrg`. The value should be the main domain of your organisation.

Alternatively you can look at the `X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality`header. If the value here is `Originating` it should come from inside your own organisation.

Comment: Will this header present always X-OriginatorOrg ? I am unable  to find it.

Comment: They are in my Tenant for all messages that I tested.
It could be, if you have a hybrid setup or if you have a gateway things go through that it is removed from the header.